# Retrieve comparable attributes for a product using product_id

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-attributes, compare

I want to get the comparable attributes for a product but without the help of the compare session.

I have product id and I need the list of comparable attributes that are associated with the product

Comment: Is there anyway you can clarify your question? Do you only need comparable attributes on one product?

Comment: i have list of product ids and i want this each products comparaple attributes so that i can show on the page.i am know we can get this on the compare list page but i am not using the compare session.i need just attributes

Comment: So you want to select the attributes for a product that are comparable correct?

Comment: yes..............

Answer (score 2):

I think, that you should look at method **getComparableAttributes()** of class **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Compare_Item_Collection**

```
public function getComparableAttributes()
{
    if (is_null($this->_comparableAttributes)) {
        $this->_comparableAttributes = array();
        $setIds = $this->_getAttributeSetIds();
        if ($setIds) {
            $attributeIds = $this->_getAttributeIdsBySetIds($setIds);

            $select = $this->getConnection()->select()
                ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getTable('eav/attribute')))
                ->join(
                    array('additional_table' => $this->getTable('catalog/eav_attribute')),
                    'additional_table.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id'
                )
                ->joinLeft(
                    array('al' => $this->getTable('eav/attribute_label')),
                    'al.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND al.store_id = ' . (int) $this->getStoreId(),
                    array('store_label' => $this->getConnection()->getCheckSql('al.value IS NULL', 'main_table.frontend_label', 'al.value'))
                )
                ->where('additional_table.is_comparable=?', 1)
                ->where('main_table.attribute_id IN(?)', $attributeIds);
            $attributesData = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
            if ($attributesData) {
                $entityType = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY;
                Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                    ->importAttributesData($entityType, $attributesData);
                foreach ($attributesData as $data) {
                    $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                        ->getAttribute($entityType, $data['attribute_code']);
                    $this->_comparableAttributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
                }
                unset($attributesData);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->_comparableAttributes;
}
```

as you can see can see, all attributes which option is_comparable can be used for compare.

According to it, you should get all proruduct's attributes with is_comparable=1

Foe exmaple, you can get something like:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection $attributes */
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$attributes->addFieldToFilter('additional_table.is_comparable', array('1'));

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection();
foreach ($attributes->getItems() as $attribute)
{
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attribute->getAttributeCode());
}

$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array(1, 5, 6));
```

Where **entity_id** is id of needed product.